# How would I print out a user input given the certain amount of inputs needed?

Tags: java, loops

How would I print out a user input given the certain amount of inputs needed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SilentAuction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
            System.out.println();//need to write "int sm = sc.nextInt;" and "String s = sc.nextLine;"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(sc.nextInt());`?

Comment: pro tip: use summarized titles instead of very long titles, and put the rest of the information in the body

Comment: When you say, amounts of input. Do you mean the amount entered by the user or the number of characters/digits entered? I see the class name is SilentAuction. So, are you trying to compare previously entered amount with the current amount? Or are you trying to find the highest amount bid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to hit a [common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) if you mix `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` methods. You'd be better off using `nextLine()` and trying to parse the content.

```
public class SilentAuction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            int sm = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(s + " : " + sm);
        }
    }
}
```